# Python library for GraphDB

Tags: graphdb

Is there a Python library out there for importing TTL files into GraphDB? I.e. Just point it at a file, rather than loop through millions of statements and inserting them individually?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't know about a specific python library for this, but you can use the [repository statements](https://rdf4j.org/documentation/reference/rest-api/#repository-statements) endpoint to upload your data.

Something like this seems to work:

```
import requests

headers = {
  'Content-Type': 'application/x-turtle',
  'Accept': 'application/json'
}

with open('sample.ttl', 'rb') as f:
  requests.post('http://localhost:7200/repositories/test/statements', data=f, headers=headers)
```

If the data is really big you should probably consider either the [loadrdf](https://graphdb.ontotext.com/documentation/free/loading-data-using-the-loadrdf-tool.html) or the [preload](https://graphdb.ontotext.com/documentation/free/loading-data-using-preload.html) tools.

Comment: It's test data of the order of 100m statements, so relatively big. The command line tool will be perfect. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

There is a rather fresh probably unstable [library](https://github.com/patzomir/graphdb-python-api) you could use.

It (presumably) includes all the available interfaces for GraphDB.

A turtle import can be executed as:

```
from graphdb.rdf4j.api.repositories_api import RepositoriesApi
from graphdb.rdf4j.configuration import Configuration
from graphdb.rdf4j.api_client import ApiClient
from graphdb.mime_types import RDFTypes


conf = Configuration()
conf.host = "http://localhost:7200/"
api_client = ApiClient(configuration=conf)
api_client.set_default_header("Content-Type", RDFTypes.TURTLE)
repository = "tеst"
api = RepositoriesApi(api_client)
api.put_statements(repository, rdf_data="@prefix ex: <http://test/> . \
    ex:1 ex:p ex:2 . ")
```